# How to display images to match prediction data with a keras datagen?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, conv-neural-network

[image]
[image]

My test_data (Used to feed into the CNN AI for predictions) is not showing the data I want properly. I have managed to only show data through a forloop (Which is commented out) but this only shows random images. I thought that I could trying choosing specific images to match with the predictions (Predictions are called classes on code) but it is not working as I cannot show the images correctly.

I have managed to show it randomly in a forloop (which is commented out)
I am expecting to match the prediction number (classes shape is: 172, 2. Being 172 groups with two prediction numbers.) and I am trying to show these with the correct image it predicted.

Note:
Classes is a numpy.ndarray.
Test_set is a Keras Datagen (containing images) that went through a ImageDataGenerator.

Goal: I want to show match the prediction data with the testset.
If anything else is required that I have not included, please feel free to ask. And thankyou in advance!

Comment: I hovered over test_set and it said that it is actually a directoryIterator

Comment: Please upload code as text rather than images.

Comment: Hello and thankyou. I actually did in another question. I will read the other answer here too as I have only just seen it. Thankyou to the other person who answered. Meanwhile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341738/how-do-i-display-the-right-image-with-the-right-prediction?noredirect=1#comment131251226_74341738

Answer (score 0):

train_generator.flow_from_directory is not random you can name your sample to make them pick it up in order or sequences. The train_generator.flow_from_directory also attached class_name as folders name or custom value with its result too. ( I use this as the template for some data sources they accept train_generator or iteration loop when types are not allowed or pre-conditions )

Sample: Iterator allowed for the dataset, not train_generator.

```
for x in train_generator:
    print( x[1] )
    squeeze = tf.squeeze( tf.constant( x[0] ) )
    expand = tf.expand_dims(squeeze, axis=2)
    image = tf.keras.utils.array_to_img( expand, data_format=None, scale=True, dtype=None )
    plt.imshow( image )
    plt.show()
```

Sample: Prediction image from list of images

```
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_label_actual[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
```

Sample: << What is the list directory look like !? Yes, it is access allowed from permissions try copy coms files over or open cannot read >>

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
IMAGE_SIZE = ( 21, 16 ) 
BATCH_SIZE = 1

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Function
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def gen():
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        # rescale=1./255,
        # shear_range=0.2,
        # zoom_range=0.2,
        # horizontal_flip=True 
        )
    train_generator = train_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'F:\\temp\\image_catagorize',
        classes=[ 'plane', 'helicopter', 'truck' ],
        target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        color_mode='grayscale',
        class_mode='sparse',    # None  # categorical   # binary    # sparse
        subset='training')

    return train_generator
    
train_generator = gen()
val_generator = train_generator

for x in train_generator:
    squeeze = tf.squeeze( tf.constant( x[0] ) )
    expand = tf.expand_dims(squeeze, axis=2)
    image = tf.keras.utils.array_to_img( expand, data_format=None, scale=True, dtype=None )
    plt.imshow( image )
    plt.show()
```